# Crashlytics upload issue (statusCode 503)

Tags: ios, crashlytics

I'm having an issue with Crashlytics dSYM upload build phase on CI.
The script fails with the following error:

```
Crashlytics: XXX.app.dSYM could not be uploaded statusCode 503
XXX Slice:armv7
XXX Slice:armv7s
XXX Slice:arm64
```

Local build succeeds.
Does anyone have ideas what can cause this problem?

The build phase is common for crashlytics:

```
./Crashlytics.framework/run <APIKey copy-pasted from crashlytics plugin> <Some other key copy-pasted from crashlytics plugin>
```

Crashlytics version is 1.3.9.

```
Crashlytics.framework/run 1.3.9
```

Comment: Show us your code, please.

Comment: I have updated the post by adding the contents of build phase.

Comment: I have the same issue on Xcode bots, working fine on normal Xcode build

Comment: Having same problems too, error occurs only when build on Apple CI, manual build works ok. Issue did not exist on Friday.

Comment: Seems that https://www.crashlytics.com guys do perform updates, as their services are not available right now. This is causing this error

Comment: Have same problem. Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much of an answer... but it is working now :)

Comment: True, looks like they fixed it.